# how to use certificates file and ssl on c# selfhost webApi?

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, x509certificate

I implimenting a server using selfhost webApi. 
I need to use ssl with certificates that will load a .cer file ( = Used to store a public key ) that will be load from disk when the server will start.

I loaded the the .cer file

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(fullpath, password);

but i don't know how to set the webapi to use this certificate  file.

I don't find any example or how to do it.

Any help please

Thanks

Comment: How are you hosting the API. In IIS on your own server, or in Azure etc?

Comment: no, i doing self host.

Comment: You should not use the code. Go and learn `netsh http` command to see how to set up certificate mapping for HTTPS. That's how certificates are used and your Web API host process should then simply hook to the HTTPS binding.